# Non square matrix multiplication operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, lp-spaces, matrix-rank

Let $A(x), x\in (0,1)$ an $2\times n$ matrix, with $n\geq 2$.

Consider the multiplication operator $K$ on $[L^2(0,1)]^n$ defined as $$K: f(x) \mapsto Kf(x)=A(x).f(x).$$
Intuitively,  $$K: [L^2(0,1)]^n \rightarrow [L^2(0,1)]^2,$$
is onto if and only if $A(x)$ is a full rank matrix for any $x \in (0,1)$. Is that right?

- I'm looking for some references that deal with this kind of non-square multiplication operator.
  Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean $A(x)$ is a full rank matrix for any $x$? The elements of $A$ are operators themselves mapping $L^2(0,1)\to L^2(0,1)$.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for an assumption that guarantees that K is onto. I couldn't see that.

Comment: It's not clear what full rank means since $L^2(0,1)^2$ is infinite dimensional. Is what you're asking for equivalent statement of $K$ being continuous, or that it be surjective, or that its image is dense?

Comment: Yes sir, the question was about the subjectivity pf $K$. What assumption guarantees that $K$ is onto.